# How should i catch and handle 406 error in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, user-interface

I have a route where i send to the api the day and h to verify in database if there is an opening in a schedule, if is not the api is sending 406. And i'm getting in console 406 error.
How should i handle that error to have a clean console?

Comment: kindly post some of your code/efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle or CodePen with the code you have tried to let people debug your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap an api call into try-catch and simply don't to do anything with `e` in catch part.

```
try { ... you code here ... } catch(e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Axios for API calls you can create a global interceptor and return a response based on your status code to your component.
This would go in your main.js.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
 if(err.response.status === 406){
       //your code here.
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your call in a `try{} catch(e) {}` to handle what happens after the error happens

**but it is impossible to prevent the browser from showing the error in the console** programmatically because of the potential risk that a script might misuse the errored requests to hide its activities from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
check_time(day,hour){
    var fields = {};
    fields.day = parseInt(day);
    fields.hour = parseInt(hour);

    try {
        this.$http.post('courses/check', fields)
    } catch {
        this.$store.dispatch('alert', {'message': 'Already exist a course in this interval.'});
    }

}
```